# How to fix a bug in the Basic Fragments example code from the official Android tutorial

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have downloaded the example code for the official Fragments tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html), after updating it to use gradle and work with the latest version of Android Studio, I found it throws a NullPointerException when clicking on an article and when running on an emulator with a large screen (i.e. tablet sized screen - on a phone sized screen it works fine). You can find the updated code [here](https://github.com/alexspurling/android-fragment-basics). The exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.fragmentbasics.ArticleFragment.updateArticleView(ArticleFragment.java:64)
    at com.example.fragmentbasics.MainActivity.onArticleSelected(MainActivity.java:66)
    at com.example.fragmentbasics.HeadlinesFragment.onListItemClick(HeadlinesFragment.java:75)
    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:60)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
```

As far as I understand, the layout article_view should be inflated into the main activity when the fragment ArticleFragment is created. This layout has a TextView with the id "article". This should happen regardless of the screen size.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
}
```

But for some reason, later on when updateArticleView is called on ArticleFragment, no view with the id "article" is found which causes the NPE above.

```
public void updateArticleView(int position) {
    TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);
    article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);
    mCurrentPosition = position;
}
```

What changes do we need to make to the example code to avoid this NPE and make the sample code work in all screen sizes?

**Update:**

The issue has been resolved thanks to Roberto Martucci's answer below. I have updated the master branch of the github repository to include the fix.

Comment: This is a very small problem, check your `article_view.xml` is available only for `main/res/layout`. If you want to use it on large screen then you have to create `article_view.xml` in `main/res/layout-large` also.

Comment: I have just tried your updated code, and it works perfectly.

Comment: is you tried on large screen phone ? @arcticwhite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a fragment, you should call `findViewById` on its root view and not on the activity content. Apply these changes to avoid the exception:

```
private View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false)
   return rootView;
}

public void updateArticleView(int position) {
    if(rootView != null) {
        TextView article = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.article);
        article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);
    }
    mCurrentPosition = position;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tested your code and I probably found the solution. You have to add `article_view.xml` to layout-large as previously suggested in the other answers but it has to have the following structure. Your `TextView` needs to have a parent container, so I wrapped it in a `FrameLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Is the type of rootView supposed to be ViewGroup or View? The former fails to compile and using the latter, I still get the same NPE. I have also tried copying article_view.xml to layout-large as suggested by @Heisen-berg. I have pushed the code to a new branch here if you want to try it yourself: https://github.com/alexspurling/android-fragment-basics/tree/suggested-fixes

Comment: You're right, rootView is a View. I edited the answer.

Comment: I edited my answer with a fix that I think should work for large layout devices. Check if it helps

Comment: Thank you! The new article_view.xml works great now.

Comment: Happy to hear it ;)

Answer (score 0):

After checking a little bit, I found it...

Your structure has to be like this:

```
layout
   -article_view.xml
   -news_articles.xml
layout-small
   -article_view.xml
layout-large
   -article_view.xml
layout-xlarge
    -article_view.xml
```

Tried it, and it's working.

Edit: Or any other way, but you have to have `article_view.xml` inside all these folders.

Comment: Sorry, this structure still does not work for me. I have tried several emulated tablet devices including the Nexus 7 and the Nexus 7 2012 both of which should be using the "large" layout. What device are you emulating when you test it? What API version is the device using?

Comment: @AlexSpurling I was using `Acer ICONIA ONE 8 B1-810` and the `API` is `4.4.4`